# Get IIS website into version control

Tags: version-control, powershell, iis-7.5, msdeploy

**The Problem:** Until now, I create a IIS website/app using the IIS manager tool. The problem is that changes to a IIS website aren't documented as they should be. For example: when I update the URL Rewrite rules this changes should be documented in a version control solution.

What is your solution to solve this issus?

Answer (score 0):

Using a source control is possible in any project type, including "Website" or "Web Application" projects. Are you going to establish a [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)?

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant that I want the IIS website to be in source control. I actuality want to integrate it with my CI solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have your project in source control.  Then create a build in [PowerShell and/or MSBuild](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2010/08/24/installing-web-applications-using-web-deploy-msbuild-and-powershell.aspx) that can deploy your website to a clean IIS (or at least with all dependencies there).  That will document the steps needed to deploy your site.

Comment: Since the actually IIS 7 website is a web.config file, I want to have that file in source control, and than create and modified the site from this file, instead of directly in the IIS Manager.